# Unable to authenticate at docker-mailserver

Tags: ubuntu, python, docker

I am running a docker-mailserver via docker-compose. The programm seems to run fine, it doesn't give any error messages. I can add user as much as i want and stuff, everything seems to be fine. However, I am unable to authenticate with any of the added User, neither through telnet nor a simple python program.

My goal is to send an email with python through that docker-mailserver. Heres the code for that little script:

```
import smtplib, ssl

server = "name.domain.com"
port = 587
password = "password"
sender = "user@domain.com"
recipient = "some.mail@some.webmail"
message = "Subject: Test\n\nIs it really so hard?"

context = ssl.create_default_context()

try:
    server = smtplib.SMTP(server, port)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls(context=context)
    server.ehlo()
    server.login(sender, password)
    server.sendmail(sender, recipient, message)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
finally:
    server.quit()
```

The script is fairly simple and given that I clearly use the username and password I added just a moment ago throws the following Error:

```
(535, b'Incorrect authentication data')
```

I can confirm that the script works just fine as I already tried it with test gmail Account/Server which worked just a expected.

So I guess the problem is that i am unable to authenticate to the server with the given login data.
Does anyone know what's the cause and what's a solution on that problem?

It's all running on KUbuntu 18.04